# Apache mod rewrite all .zip files from my root to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website containing some `.zip` files in its `root`, and a folder called `/files/` containing other `.zip` files.

I moved all those files to another server, but I don't want to break my links, so I need to redirect `.zip` files requests arriving to my `root` and my `/files/` folder to another subdomain. I may want in the future to have a different folder on my server containing `.zip` files, so I need to redirect only

```
mydomain.com/*.zip
mydomain.com/files/*.zip
```

I wrote the rule for `/files/` and it works well (yes from that folder I need all kind of files for now, from the root only `.zip` files):

```
RewriteRule ^files/(.*) http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

But I'm stuck about doing the same with all requests for `.zip` files arriving to the `root` of my domain...any suggestion?

Comment: Have you moved the zip files in root as well as the files folder to the root of your new domain? or, have you maintained the same folder structure?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify, you're right! I moved all to the same folder on the new domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you've moved all the `zip` files to the root of your new domain use

  ```
  RewriteRule ^.*?/?([^/]+\.zip)$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
  ```
- If you've maintained the same folder structure (i.e. you want to move `/files/*.zip` to `newdomain.com/files/*.zip`) use

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.+\.zip)$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
  ```
- Keep your current rule that redirects everything under `/files/` at the top.

  ```
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*) http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
  ```

  Then when you only want to redirect the `/files/*.zip` simple turn it off with a `#` in front of it.

`[QSA]` is not required because we haven't touched the query string here.

***EDIT** :*

Okay, to redirect only

```
mydomain.com/*.zip
mydomain.com/files/*.zip
```

Use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^(?:files/)?([^/]+\.zip)$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I moved all files to the root of new domain, so I used the first rule RewriteRule ^.*/?([^/]+\.zip)$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L] but it does not work...firstdomain.com/File2.zip becomes newdomain.com/2.zip , so the word "File" is stripped off..??

Comment: Ah, it starts with `^.*?/?`. Notice an extra `?` before `/` as well. Please try again.

Comment: That works, and I found also another way, the problem is that it works also for other folders! So if I call http://mydomain.com/anotherfolder/file.zip it redirects as well to new domain, and I want it to do it only for .zip files in the root OR .zip files in the "files" folder. All the other .zip files in all the other subfolders must not redirect...and I'm really lost about how to ever do this.

Comment: @opoloko, removed the global `.zip` redirect. Now only the `.zip` files in `/` and `/files` would get redirected. Don't lose hope. It's gonna work this time just the way you want. :)

Comment: Thanks! That works indeed...I seriously always struggle with rewrite and how to specifically target the start and end of an url requested..do you have any link/guide I can read to understand more? Thanks again, it works beautifully and with one line!

Comment: Check out Apache's official website to get to know all the directives like `RewriteCond`, `RewriteRule` and the variables like `%{REQUEST_URI}` etc. that you can use in an `.htaccess` file. The next thing to learn is how to write regular expressions for pattern matching your URLs. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best online resource for that.